# Dropping -re at the end of a verb - pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I'm watching a movie whose story takes place in Rome. People often drop the -RE ending in verb infinitives. Example:

> Sai che l'avvocato è l'unico che può farti uscire?

The speaker pronounces "uscire" in this sentence as /uʃi/. I have already seen letters dropped in others languages as a result of lazy pronunciation. Is that the case here or is it a feature of the Roman accent?

Comment: Not sure who talks like this. A feature of Roman dialect is to omit the whole syllable “-re” from infinitives (_volere_ > _vole'_, _avere_ > _ave'_, _andare_ > _anna'_ and so on). Wouldn't you happen to have an extract from that film, say on YouTube, or at least could you say who is the actor who talks like this?

Comment: @DaG Hearing the dialogue again, now I think that "uscire" is indeed pronounced /uʃi/ . I have corrected my question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be some central/southern dialect's form. It is **not** correct Italian.

You can actually find grammatically correct forms of truncated words in Italian.
For example,

> Sai che l'avvocato è l'unico che può farti uscir?

would be correct. It is not used in the informal/spoken language.

You usually find this form in songs, poems or "old" anthology (by "old" I mean not current).

Comment: I would like a confirmation of where this is used (only Rome or the entire central/southern Italy).

Comment: I wouldn't say this is "not correct Italian", but a regional-dialectal form of oral speech.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista it used both in Rome and parts of southern Italy

Comment: @Charo you can consider it a mispronunciation of the Italian "uscire" or the correct pronunciation of the roman/southern "uscì". In this case it is surely a dialectal expression. Either way, it is not Italiano...